# Github pages css troubles only on smartphone

Tags: html, css, jekyll, github-pages

I am creating a website using Jekyll, and publishing it using Github pages. When I `jekyll serve` the website in local, everything works fine, and it looks normal both from my computer and smartphone. But when I visit the Github pages one from my smartphone, some divs seem to be shifted a bit, and the font-awesome icons are not rendered. Strangely, it works fine when I visit it (the Github pages one) from my computer.

I am not sure where to look at. Could something happen on github and be overriding only some media queries?

I have no idea yet what is relevant in the code, but I'll try to create some MCV example. Until then, the source code is [here](http://www.github.com/Nicowcow/nicowcow.github.io) and the website is [here](http://nicowcow.github.io).

Here's the CSS, mostly taken from a Pure css layout:

```
    * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    /*
     * -- BASE STYLES --
     * Most of these are inherited from Base, but I want to change a few.
     */
        body {
            line-height: 1.7em;
            color: #7f8c8d;
            font-size: 13px;
        }

        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4,
        h5,
        h6,
        label {
            color: #34495e;
        }

        div.tweet-box {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            border-left: 3px solid #1f8dd6;
            padding: 1em 1.6em;
            font-weight: 100;
            border-radius: 5px;
            line-height: 1em;
        }

        .fat {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        a.shy-link {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #7f8c8d;
        }

        a:visited.shy-link{
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #7f8c8d;
        }

        a:hover.shy-link{
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #34495e;
        }

        .pure-img-responsive {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        /*
         * -- LAYOUT STYLES --
         * These are some useful classes which I will need
         */
        .l-box {
            padding: 0.4em;
        }

        .l-box-lrg {
            padding: 2em;
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        }

        .is-center {
            text-align: center;
        }



        /*
         * -- PURE FORM STYLES --
         * Style the form inputs and labels
         */
        .pure-form label {
            margin: 1em 0 0;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 100%;
        }

        .pure-form input[type] {
            border: 2px solid #ddd;
            box-shadow: none;
            font-size: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
        }

        /*
         * -- PURE BUTTON STYLES --
         * I want my pure-button elements to look a little different
         */
        .pure-button {
            background-color: #1f8dd6;
            color: white;
            padding: 0.5em 2em;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        a.pure-button-primary {
            background: white;
            color: #1f8dd6;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-size: 120%;
        }


        /*
         * -- MENU STYLES --
         * I want to customize how my .pure-menu looks at the top of the page
         */

        .home-menu {
            padding: 0.5em;
            text-align: center;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, 0.10);
        }
        .home-menu {
            background: #2d3e50;
        }
        .pure-menu.pure-menu-fixed {
            /* Fixed menus normally have a border at the bottom. */
            border-bottom: none;
            /* I need a higher z-index here because of the scroll-over effect. */
            z-index: 4;
        }

        .home-menu .pure-menu-heading {
            color: white;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 120%;
        }

        .home-menu .pure-menu-selected a {
            color: white;
        }

        .home-menu a {
            color: #6FBEF3;
        }
        .home-menu li a:hover,
        .home-menu li a:focus {
            background: none;
            border: none;
            color: #AECFE5;
        }


        /*
         * -- SPLASH STYLES --
         * This is the blue top section that appears on the page.
         */

        .splash-container {
            background: #1f8dd6;
            z-index: 1;
            overflow: hidden;
            /* The following styles are required for the "scroll-over" effect */
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            position: fixed !important;
        }

        .splash {
            /* absolute center .splash within .splash-container */
            width: 80%;
            height: 50%;
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        /* This is the main heading that appears on the blue section */
        .splash-head {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: white;
            border: 3px solid white;
            padding: 1em 1.6em;
            font-weight: 100;
            border-radius: 5px;
            line-height: 1em;
        }

        /*
         * -- CONTENT STYLES --
         * This represents the content area (everything below the blue section)
         */
        @keyframes blink {
            0% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            50% {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }

        .content-caret img {
            display: block;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            animation: blink 2s;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        }

        .content-caret img.content-caret-bottom {
            animation-delay: 0.1s;
            transform: translate(0, -80%);
        }

        .content-caret img.content-caret-top {
            animation-delay: 0s;
        }

        .content-wrapper {
            /* These styles are required for the "scroll-over" effect */
            position: absolute;
            top: 87%;
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 12%;
            z-index: 2;
            background: transparent;
        }

        .content-wrapper-solid {
            background: white;
        }

        /* This is the class used for the main content headers () */
        .content-head {
            font-weight: 400;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 0.1em;
            margin: 2em 0 1em;
            /*padding: 10px;*/

        }

        /* This is a modifier class used when the content-head is inside a ribbon */
        .content-head-ribbon {
            color: white;
        }

        /* This is the class used for the content sub-headers () */
        .content-subhead {
            color: #1f8dd6;
        }
        .content-subhead i {
            margin-right: 7px;
        }

        /* This is the class used for the dark-background areas. */
        .ribbon {
            background: #2d3e50;
            color: #aaa;
        }

        /* This is the class used for the footer */
        .footer {
            background: #111;
            font-size: 11px;
        }



        /*
         * -- TABLET (AND UP) MEDIA QUERIES --
         * On tablets and other medium-sized devices, we want to customize some
         * of the mobile styles.
         */
        @media (min-width: 48em) {

            /* We increase the body font size */
            body {
                font-size: 16px;
            }
            /* We want to give the content area some more padding */
            .content {
                padding: 1em;
            }

            /* We can align the menu header to the left, but float the
            menu items to the right. */
        .home-menu {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .home-menu ul {
            float: right;
        }

        /* We increase the height of the splash-container */
        /*    .splash-container {
        height: 500px;
        }*/

        /* We decrease the width of the .splash, since we have more width
        to work with */
        .splash {
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;
        }

        .splash-head {
            font-size: 250%;
        }


        /* We remove the border-separator assigned to .l-box-lrg */
        .l-box-lrg {
            border: none;
        }

    }

    /*
     * -- DESKTOP (AND UP) MEDIA QUERIES --
     * On desktops and other large devices, we want to over-ride some
     * of the mobile and tablet styles.
     */
        @media (min-width: 78em) {
            /* We increase the header font size even more */
            .splash-head {
                font-size: 300%;
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:** 
Here are a few pictures to explain what I mean.

From the Android default browser (which doesn't support CSS3 transitions and transforms, it seems): (**OK**)

[image: android default browser]

From Firefox on Android: (**NO HEADER, WEIRD BLUE BAR: NOT OK**)

[image: android firefox]

From my desktop's Firefox (resized to match a phone's dimension): (**OK**)

[image: debian firefox]

What's surprising is that it seems to only occur on firefox on Android. I also tried on an iPhone, and the result is as expected. Why that only happens from Github-pages and not from my local server is what startles me the most.

**EDIT 2:**

I just compared the css produced by Github Pages and the css produced by my server, and besides a few linebreaks and spaces here and there, they are identical. Could the difference reside in the HTML?

Comment: What do you mean by **shifted**?. Can you add a screen capture?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't right now, but the `content-wrapper` div does not seem to fit the screen width perfectly, and hence there is a 2-3 pixel bar that appears on the side.

Comment: Are you talking about the blue bar to the left of the Twitter box?

Comment: @ErikGillespie : No, that's meant to be there. I'll upload a picture in a second.

Comment: the code snippet is incomplete, there's no html. If you with to provide only the CSS portion, make it a normal code block in your question description.

Comment: @DavidJacquel : on the second picture, the white div is *shifted*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just reproduced this on Firefox 38 on Ubuntu.

While trying to find a `box-model` problem I saw this in my Firefox security console :

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css"[Learn More] nicowcow.github.io
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-min.css"[Learn More] nicowcow.github.io
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css"[Learn More]
```

Then the problem might be here ([see MDN documentation about MixedContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent)).

So, the solution is to request those three ressources over https.
This does work for Font-awesome at https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css but not for `pure` files (NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID).

You will have to host them on your server or find another provider which serve over htpps.

Comment: You are very right. It does not depend on the browser at all, rather on whether the page is accessed with http or https. Thanks a lot!